# how to disable the button using bitmapbuttonfield in advanced ui examples in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am using bitmap button field in advanced ui examples.
By default no method is working for disabling the button in 5.0 jre, 
so i have added the below code for disabling and 
then disabling functionality of the button is working but setchangelistener is not working
that is my problem
.. here is my code that i added for disabling the button..please check. do i need to change anything in invoke action method?

```
 public boolean isDisable() {
   return isDisable;
 }

 public void setDisable(boolean isDisable) {
   this.isDisable = isDisable;
 invalidate();
 }

 public boolean isFocusable() {
   return isFocusable && !isDisable;
 }

 public void setFocusable(boolean isFocusable) {
 this.isFocusable = isFocusable;
 }

 protected boolean invokeAction(int action) {
   if (!isDisable){
    fieldChangeNotify(0);
   }

       return true;
 }

 public boolean setEnabled() {
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: your code is commented out (I assume it's not that way in the program, but it's still hurts my eyes), and your `getEnabled()` method is named `setEnabled()`.  you haven't shown any `setChangeListener()` code, so we can't see how it's used.  please add that, too, if you'd like us to see what's wrong with it.  thanks.

Comment: hi Nate.. if i added the code. in my ui class. button.setchange listener is not working

Comment: https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/BaseButtonField.java

Comment: https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/BitmapButtonField.java

Comment: those are the links for classes which i have used for adding the bitmap..

Comment: final BitmapButtonField newButton = new BitmapButtonField(newBitmap,
newOverBitmap, FIELD_LEFT);

Comment: this is how i have added the bitmap using bitmap button field. if i want to disable the button. i am unable to disable the button..

Comment: Please use the **edit** button/link below the question to add to your question.  Put all the important information above.  Please also clean up the code.  Don't show us a block of unformatted, commented-out code.  Be clear about what's not working?  **"button.setchange listener is not working"** is not a clear description.  What is not working about it?  Is the `fieldChanged()` method not called back?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [discussion on the BlackBerry forums about this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-enable-disable-some-fields-based-on-checkbox-value/td-p/552247).

What I've sometimes done is actually make use of the `isEditable()` property on `Field` objects, since editability and being enabled are somewhat similar concepts.  If you really want to keep the separate `isDisabled()` code, that's fine.  Just substitute that below where I use `isEditable()` (remembering to reverse the boolean ... that's one reason to always program in the affirmative ... make your method `isEnabled()` instead of `isDisabled()`).

So, instead of any of the code you posted above, I would just add this code to either `BitmapButtonField`, or `BaseButtonField`:

```java
public boolean isFocusable() {
   return isEditable() && super.isFocusable();
}
```

and this in `BitmapButtonField`:

```java
protected void paint( Graphics g ) {
   int oldAlpha = g.getGlobalAlpha();
   int index = g.isDrawingStyleSet( Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS ) ? FOCUS : NORMAL;
   if (!isEditable()) {
      g.setGlobalAlpha(100);  // alpha is 0 to 255, so this is 100/255
   }
   g.drawBitmap( 0, 0, _bitmaps[index].getWidth(), _bitmaps[index].getHeight(), _bitmaps[index], 0, 0 );
   g.setGlobalAlpha(oldAlpha);
}
```

And then, I can setup a change listener, or disable the button, like this in my manager class:

```java
  BitmapButtonField btn = 
     new BitmapButtonField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button.png"),
                           Bitmap.getBitmapResource("button-lit.png"));

  btn.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
     public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        Dialog.alert("Button clicked!");
     }         
  });
  btn.setEditable(false);   // this disables the button
  add(btn);
```

But, understand, that if you **disable** a button, that means your change listener won't get called.  That's kind of how it's supposed to work.  The change listener is only called if the button's enabled and therefore clickable.

Also, note that in order to make the button look different when disabled (not *editable*), I override `paint()` to set a different alpha value when the button is disabled.  You didn't mention that, so if you don't like it, you can certainly take it out.